# Is there any physical significance to the fact that magnetic and electric field are proportional by $c$?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, classical-electrodynamics

Being that this relation can be derived from Maxwell's equations, is there any physical significance to it outside the fact that the same equations make it the phase velocity of EM waves?

Comment: $F=q(E+v\times B)$, so a particle moving with speed comparable to $c$ will experience roughly equal forces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is entirely a feature of the system of units chosen. In [Gaussian units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units) the fields in a free-space light-wave have the same amplitudes, but the Lorentz force law has the form
$$ \mathbf{F} = q\left(\mathbf{E} + \frac{\mathbf{v}}{c} \times \mathbf{B}\right) \;.$$

---

It is very easy to get the impression that Gaussian units are *"just cgs instead of mks"*, but they also have a different dimensional structure to how charge is dealt with so there are big differences in the way equations are wrtten.